# How does ::selection's specificity work against type selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, w3c, pseudo-element

Some questions about using CSS to specify the color of selected text:

Imagine that a rule like the following exists in the default CSS that's implemented by the browser:

```
::selection { background-color: Highlight; color: HighlightText; }
```

Further imagine that a rule like the following is defined in any site-specific authored stylesheet:

```
body { background-color: white }
```

1. Given these rules, what would the `background-color` of the selected body text be? Would it be `white`, or `Highlight`?

   Perhaps the rule in the author stylesheet should override the default rule: because according to specificity, `body` is just as specific as `::selection` and is specified later (and should therefore override the previous entry).

   On the other hand, that would result in text being invisible when it's selected (because if `Highlight` is blue and `HighlightText` is white so that selected text is white-on-blue, then overriding the `background-color` of selected text so that it's white would result in its being white-on-white).
2. Assuming that the behaviour in step 2 is undesirable, how to avoid it?

- Say that it's a bug in the user stylesheet, which shouldn't ever specify `background-color` without also specifying `color`?
- Say that `body` isn't a match for selected body text except when the `::selection` pseudo-element is specified as part of the selector?

Comment: It looks like part #1 of your question ("Why was it dropped?") should exist as a separate question altogether, since the accepted answer doesn't address that anyway. You can ask it as a new question now, as it's confirmed that it's been dropped, and there is a reason for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Type selectors (e.g. `body`) and pseudo-element selectors (e.g. `::selection`) do indeed have the same specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), but **specificity only comes into play when two selectors select the same element**.

The `body` selector doesn’t select selected text, or any text at all — it selects the `<body>` element. It’s the element, and not its text, that has the background-color.

Whereas `::selection` selects an imaginary element that surrounds currently selected text on the page. So there’s no conflict between styles set on `body` and `::selection`, because the selectors select different things.

#### Example

Imagine you had the following HTML:

```html
<body>
    I am some body text.

    <p>I am some text in a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

And the following CSS:

```
p {
    background-color: red;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Both selectors have the same specificity, but the `<p>`’s background will still be red, because it’s not the `<body>` element.

The same is true if you replace `p` with `::selection` — selected text’s background will be red, because text within the `<body>` element is not the `<body>` element.

So, basically, what you said here:

> `body` isn't a match for selected body text except when the `::selection` pseudo-element is specified as part of the selector

Comment: OK I think you're saying that the processing is as if the DOM looked like this: `<body>Some <::selection>selected</::selection> text.</body>` and so because a background-color value is associated with the `::selection` pseudo-element therefore the text doesn't get its style from `<body>` which is the now the text's grandparent node, not its parent node.

Comment: @ChrisW: **bingo**. The only slight correction I’d make to your statement is that, strictly speaking, text never gets a `background-color` style. Imagine every DOM element creates a box around its contents. It’s that box that gets the background colour, not the text itself. Whereas with a property like `color`, the text is one of a number of things that gets the style. (Any border or outline on the box also get the style.)

Comment: The current (as of Jan 2012) [Last Call draft of CSS3 UI](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/#changes-list) now simply states, "The ::selection pseudo-element has been dropped since it was dropped from Selectors after testing found interoperability problems and further details to explore/define." One of the major problems was with propagation of styles to descendant elements, which is covered in depth [in this mailing list thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0268.html). (Should I post this as an answer instead since it addresses the OP's first question?)

Comment: Basically, this means that `::selection` is gone from CSS3 for good. It has not been forgotten, though; the WG just needs to sort those details out (I'm eagerly watching the discussion), and who knows — they may slate it for return in CSS4 UI in the coming years.

Comment: I've also trimmed our chatty comments at the start so as to avoid detracting from the discussion at hand.

Comment: @BoltClock comment update time; it's back in pseudo-selectors level 4

Comment: @TylerH: I think enough work has been done on ::selection in the last decade that this question and all its answers are moot - maybe a historical lock would apply, considering the nature of the question.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree a historical lock is probably a good idea.

Comment: @TylerH: Now that you've safely removed the problematic (for lack of a better word) portion of the question I don't feel like locking it anymore. All it needs is an up to date answer reflecting the new spec... unfortunately I don't think I'm up for writing one at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The following style:

```
body { background-color: white }
```

applies to background color of your page.

On the other hand, this rule:

```
::selection { background-color: Highlight; color: HighlightText; }
```

applies styles when you ***select*** text on your page.

So they do completely different things and there is no question of collision between them.

Comment: Are you saying that the `body` rule applies to text in the body, but doesn't apply to selected text in the body?

Comment: If so that wouldn't match the behaviour of selectors vis a vis other pseudo-elements: for example an `a` selector applies to every anchor, regardless of whether the anchor has been visited.

Comment: Or if the author-specified `body` rule does apply to all text, including to selected text, then doesn't it override the `::selection` rule which was implicitly specified earlier? If not then why not?

Comment: your backwards. psuedo-classes only override styles when they are active. so text will be highlighted when they are selected and return to white when they are not.

Comment: "yes you got it right body rule does not apply to selection." - Why does it not? It seems to me that it has the same 'specificity' as the implicit `::selection` rule.

Comment: @OldCode101: “your backwards. psuedo-classes only override styles when they are active” — `::selection` is actually a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why was it removed?**

Well that would be a question you would have to ask of the W3C committee that removed it from the draft. My understanding is there has been a lot of internal turmoil within the W3C community since they began writing the HTML5 and CSS3 drafts. Certain individuals that run projects developing the browsers (and I wont go into names) wanted it done one way, and developers be damned. The developer community wanted it done another way, and so began feud over who should control the W3C.

> **Given these rules, what would the background color of selected body text be: would it be white, or Highlight?**

Sarfraz hit it on the head here, the :selection pseudo-class will only effect selected text. So in your example when you highlight something the background color changes to Highlight, when it is unselected it returns to white.

I haven't tested this particular example but here is what I understand of it

Comment: I understand that `::selected` only aplies to selected text. My question is whether `body` also applies to selected text, and whether it overrides the `::selected` rule (and if not then why not).

Comment: Body text applies to everything. :selected overrides the value of body when active, body does not override the value of :selected.

Comment: "body does not override the value of :selected" - Why not? It seems to be to have the same specificity, and is soecified later? The algorithm for cascade order says, "if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins".

Comment: the difference is body is an element, and :selected is a psuedo-class. Your definition would be true if we were discussing two elements.

Comment: `::selection` is a pseudo-element.

Comment: I read the specs as saying that the one is an element name and that the other is a pseudoelement, which according to `(= d)` of [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) are equally specific.

Answer (score 0):

`::selection` will override the background color once the selection is made, and will bring it back to the `body{background-color: white;}` once the text is deselected.
we just have to make sure to always give a proper color and background values to both the selection and the main style.