# ::-moz-selection possible bug

Tags: css, firefox

I am currently changing the default background color of selected text. This works fine:

```
::selection {
background:#B6D0FA;
}

::-moz-selection {
background:#B6D0FA;
}
```

I thought I could save some lines by merging them like this:

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection {
background:#B6D0FA;
}
```

But it doesn't work in FireFox.

**What is wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox can't parse `::selection`, which is why it needs `::-moz-selection` in the first place. Upon encountering `::selection`, the entire block is ignored.

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets):

> When a user agent cannot parse the selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS
>   2.1), it must ignore the selector and the following declaration block (if any) as well.

You will have to keep on them separate lines for this to render correctly in Firefox.

Keep in mind that `::selection` was [removed from the CSS3 draft entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499918/why-was-selection-removed-from-the-css-selectors-spec-and-how-does-its-specif).

Comment: One should be able to merge every possible combination, separate them with commas, and give `background:#B6D0FA;` with no fear of the entire code not working just because it couldn't parse one single CSS rule

Comment: @ajax333221 As much as you might wish for it, that's not a great idea. If the CSS is invalid, there is every reason for the user agent to stop parsing. Creating workarounds solely for certain off-draft implementations would be rather hackish and contra the whole idea of standards.

Comment: @ajax333221: If one did not use unsupported CSS selectors, one would not have to fear their code not working in the first place.